# Can't play audio in android using MediaPalyer

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player

I have file location in `05-11 22:43:41.793: D/Play audio(9996): /storage/emulated/0/QRSpeech/sounds/Introduction_to_Android_1.3gpp`

I want to play this file using `MediaPlayer` like the code below :

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tempDestFile); 
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

where the `tempDestFile` is file path as printed above.

No sound is heard ? why ?

Comment: So, what's the problem? What happens when you run that code?

Answer (score 0):

i've had this problem as well and tried several things. Try experimenting with `MediaPlayer.create(Uri uri)`. Get your media's path and, if it's a string, convert it to Uri.

Another reason it could not be working is a context issue. Can you post the full code where you're using the MediaPlayer?